# Is it possible to use a product expression as a constraint in an Ompr optimisation?

Tags: r, optimization, linear-programming, glpk

I'm aware of the `sum_expr` function in the `ompr` package as a way to create a constraint with a dynamic sum. However, I'm wondering if there's a way to create a constraint that uses the product instead of the sum. Or is this is not possible in *linear* optimisation?

For example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ROI)
library(ROI.plugin.glpk)
library(ompr)
library(ompr.roi)

n <- 20
score <- round(runif(n, 0, 25))
penalties <- round(runif(n, 0, 25))

model <- MIPModel() %>%
  add_variable(x[i], i = 1:n, type = "binary") %>%
  set_objective(sum_expr(score[i] * x[i], i = 1:n), "max") %>%
  add_constraint(sum_expr(penalties[i] * x[i], i = 1:n) <= 100)

result <- solve_model(model, with_ROI(solver = "glpk", verbose = TRUE))
result$solution
```

Instead of `add_constraint(sum_expr())`, is there a way of doing `add_constraint(product_expr())`?

If it's not possible with linear optimisation, where should I be looking instead?

Comment: [nloptr package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nloptr/vignettes/nloptr.pdf) is the way to go

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent nloptr does not support binary variables AFAIK

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Sorry, I missed this assumption, indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find an answer to my original question. In case of use to anyone the constraint I needed was:

```
add_constraint(sum_expr(x[i] * log(penalties[i]), i = 1:n) >= log(100))
```

So in words, I'm summing the log transformed penalty values (for which `x[i] = 1`) against the log transformed penalty total, to mimic a product constraint.

My original question erroneously implied something that likely misled readers. I was looking for the product of all penalties for which `x[i] = 1`. Not the product of the values `(penalties[i] * x[i])` which as soon as any `x[i] = 0` becomes 0.

Answer (score 1):

The product of binary variables can be linearized as follows.

Suppose we want to model

```
y = prod(i, x(i))
x(i), y ∈ {0,1}
```

We can write this as a set of linear inequalities:

```
y ≤ x(i)   ∀i
y ≥ sum(i, x(i)) - card(i) + 1
x(i), y ∈ {0,1}
```

where `card(i)` is the number of i's. Often things can be simplified further, but that depends on the details of the model.

This can be implemented straightforwardly in OMPR, and can be solved with any linear MIP solver.